# Is there a way to set "Allow access to Azure services" in Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers using Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-postgresql

I've been working with `Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers` resource and Azure Bicep specifically using [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.dbforpostgresql/servers?tabs=bicep). I am missing parameter to set my database accessable from Azure resouces (see the picture attached).

[image]

I thought `publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'` should do the trick, but it's not. Any thoughts / recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Allow access to Azure services` setting can be scripted using a firewall rule for IP `0.0.0.0`:

```bicep
param serverName string

resource server 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers@2017-12-01' existing = {
  name: serverName
}

resource allowAllWindowsAzureIps 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules@2017-12-01' = {
  name: 'AllowAllWindowsAzureIps' // don't change the name
  parent: server
  properties: {
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are not only Azure's IPs afaik, these are for anything. I use this approach to whitelist my current IP in order to use psql client from my computer and connect to the DB. But what if I want only Azure's network..?

Comment: This is the equivalent to `Allow access to Azure services`.  if you set this setting to false and run the bicep bicep it will set the setting back to yes.

Comment: what you have probably done is whitelist from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255` = every possible ips